# Need help in putting the single quote and constant timestamp in plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql-developer

Please help me in appending the Single quotes and constant timestamp to my query output. Given below is the expected output from my param file.

Note: Query is executed through sqlplus

Expected output in spool file(params.txt):

```
'12-DEC-2014'
'15-DEC-2014 23:59:59'
```

Script:

```
spool C:\output\params.txt
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
variable from_date varchar2(30);
variable to_date varchar2(30);
set verify off 
set feedback off 
set trimspool on 
set linesize 1000
set term off 
set colsep , 
set pagesize 0
set heading on
set underline off

begin
  :From_date := '&1';
  :To_date := '&2';
end; /

select to_date(:From_date,'dd-mon-yyyy') from Scehma.table1;
select to_date(:To_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from Scehma.table1;
exit 0;
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add single quotes in a string literal, just double it, or use the `chr` function.

E.g. `'hello '' world'` represents the string `hello ' world`. `'hello '||char(39)||' world'` is the same. `''''` is a string literal representing a single single-quote.

To get your fixed end time, just concatenate it.

```
select ''''||to_date(:From_date,'dd-mon-yyyy')||'''' from Scehma.table1;
select ''''||to_date(:To_date,  'dd-mon-yyyy')||' 23:59:59''' from Scehma.table1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate respone, it is working as expected.